# Using Ramda curry + placeholder with TypeScript results in "Type 'Placeholder' is not assignable to type 'x'

Tags: typescript, parameters, ramda.js, currying

I want to bind known arguments to a callback with Ramda and leave the rest unspecified:

```
import * as R from "ramda";

type Params = Partial<{
  param1: number;
  param2: number;
  param3: number;
}>;

function getBoundCallback(params: Params) {
  const { param1, param2, param3 } = params;

  const callback = (p1: number, p2: number, p3: number) => {
    // do something
  };

  return R.curry(callback)(
    param1 || R.__, 
    param2 || R.__, 
    param3 || R.__
  );
}
```

but I get:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'number | Placeholder' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
      Type 'Placeholder' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

What is the correct way to do this?

The only solution I can think of is this:

```
const callback = (
    _p1: number | R.Placeholder,
    _p2: number | R.Placeholder,
    _p3: number | R.Placeholder
  ) => {
    const p1 = _p1 as number;
    const p2 = _p2 as number;
    const p3 = _p3 as number;

    // do something
  };
```

which is far from optimal.

What is the correct way to do this?

I use `"types/npm-ramda#dist"` for Ramda type declarations.